# Can you transform an "async-keyword asynchronous" function into a "non-async-keyword asynchronous" one?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Imagine the following function is defined in some other parts of the code or a 3rd party library:

```
public async Task<int> MyAsync()
```

Is it possible to transform that into a function that is exactly the same, but just lacks the `async` keyword? For example something like this:

```
public Task<int> MyAsync2()
{
    ...
    var res = MyAsync();
    ...
 }
```

Basically, I want this function:

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    var i = await MyAsync();
    ...
}
```

and this function:

```
public async Task Foo2()
{
    var i = await MyAsync2();
    ...
}
```

to have the **same exact runtime behavior**. If `MyAsync` executes the async code with the current context (e.g UI context), then `MyAsync2` should too. The two should be interchangeable.

Is this possible?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want. Do you want a **synchronous** method as a wrapper to an **asynchronous** method call? So you could use the same method sync or async?

Comment: No, I want the same exact **asynchronous** method but I want to be able to ditch the "async" keyword

Comment: Would you mind telling us why don't you want to use the `async` keyword?

Comment: I was under the impression that any client that called it would also need `async`, but I was wrong. I want, for instance, to be able to call this method from a .NET 4.0 method (using inversion of control), but like dvorn mentioned it's pretty simple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public Task<int> MyAsync2()
{
    return MyAsync();
}
```

However I do not understand why you ever need that: async modifier is an implementation detail and it does not change the API of the method.  For instance, if MyAsync was implementing some interface, the interface would be

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    Task<int> MyAsync();
}
```

Comment: I should have tried a simple example first and see if it compiled, because it is as easy as you stated

Answer (score 0):

It is possible doing your way, but what is the point of having MyAsync2() method returning task without marking it as async?

I also notice that inside MyAsync2() method, you call MyAsync() synchronously.

```
var res = MyAsync();
```

Please note that the type of res variable is a Task. To get the result from a task without blocking current thread is using await:

```
var res = await MyAsync();
```

But, if you you use await keyword inside body of a method, your MyAsync2() method should be marked with async keyword, unless you wait for the task to complete synchronously, which is NOT recommended:

```
var res = MyAsync();
var result = res.Result;
// or => var result = MyAsync().Result;
```

So, my answer is possible syntactically, but semantically there is no point for doing that, worse it can lead a subtle error, for example firing an asynchronous task running and forget.